# TortoiseGit log - can I view only branch and merge commits?

Tags: git, version-control, tortoisegit, git-log

When dealing with a code base, I'd like to see a kind of high-level map of its history, potentially of many branches at once. This is difficult when the history has lots of commits, as a series of commits in a single branch can easily fill up the screen.

**Is there an easy way to view only branches and merges, such that all the commits within branches are hidden?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the Log dialog, you can control which commits are shown by opening the "Walk Behavior" menu at the bottom of the dialog. There you can select "Compressed Graph".

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-showlog.html

An alternative would be to open the TortoiseGit context menu in explorer on a versioned folder and select "Revision Graph" (you might need to hold the <kbd>shift</kbd>-key when opening the context menu). Maybe you also want to enable "Show branchings and mergings" in the view menu.

cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-revgraph.html

Answer (score 0):

In TortoiseGit's log, click Walk Behavior > Compressed Graph.